# Building an image of docker SQL Server with a specific set of data

Tags: bazel

What I am trying to do is build a docker of a SQL Server database and restore a specific data base in it. and create an image with this to use it later for testing purposes.

I wrote a shell script that does that.

But I am failing to find a way in https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker to do that.

```
container_image(
    name = "mssql_crm_db",
    base = "@docker_mssql//image",
    env = {
        "ACCEPT_EULA": "Y",
        "SA_PASSWORD": "Test1234",
    },
    directory = '/tmp/',
    files = [
        "//tools/mssql-docker-crm:DB_restore.bak",
        "//tools/mssql-docker-crm:restore_db_bak.sh",
    ],
    ports = [
        "1433/tcp",
    ]
)
```